# Read excel files with different schema is not supported now in Dataflow (ADF)?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am having a lot of excel files in the data lake. I am trying to read in dataflow and getting below error

"Read excel files with different schema is not supported now."

All my excel files are in the same format having the same column names. However, it's still coming above error.

[image]

Nor sure what is the issue? Can anyone advise how to solve this?

Comment: my suggest, you can ingest this excel to blob storage first ...

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a known issue and is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-errors#error-code-df-excel-differentschemanotsupport) in the official MS docs. Can please try their recommendations.

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You most likely intend to pull from multiple sheets in a folder. All the sheets do not have the same schema and that's the issue I had.

You'd need to identify the file with a different schema or take out the file path where it says wildcard path
[Remove content from the wildcard path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcSUz.png)